# Access the outlets of UIViewController but the outlets is still nil

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `UIViewController` that I want to add to embed in a `UINavigationController`

the `UIViewController` is created through the interface builder and I added a `UILabel` and created an outlet for it.

In my `UINavigationController`

```
ViewController *con = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];    
[con setMyLabelText:@"my new text"];

[navController setViewControllers:@[con] animated:NO];
```

But the `UILabel` is never set to "my new text" , it seems that the `UILabel` is not completely initialized.
When will I know that all the outlets are completely set??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you initialise a view controller, its view will not get loaded immediately. So the outlets will be nil. The view will be loaded only when it actually requirs means some one has to access its `view` property.

Why don't you set the label from the controllers `viewDidLoad` method

```
[self setMyLabelText:@"my new text"];
```

If that is not possible, force the view controller to load the `View`

```
[con view];  // Access the view explicitly, this is a hack to load the view
[con setMyLabelText:@"my new text"];
```